# How to put an attribute value in "from Min" from "Attribute map range" node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it somehow possible to put an attribute value in From Min/From Max?

[image]

What i want is to have control over e.g. scales of all distributed instances.

i want to scale them randomly...

e.g. from start frame between 20 to 100 and
with end frame between 120 and 150
and scale randomly.

So every instance should scale different (different time + duration).

Comment: I think not. Those are fixed float parameters, not per-element. Can you give an idea of  your particular case? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: @RobinBetts: i improved my question. See example here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9y8y.gif. there i scaled each individually randomly...but it was a pain in the ass with a lot of nodes :( if i could have attributes, it would be much easier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Map Range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5732390) operation is basically a shortcut to a number of mathematical atomic operations.

You can emulate its behaviour by using regular [Attribute Math](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_math.html) Nodes.

Using the formula from the first link I suggested, I laid out the algorithm :

```
output = output_start + ((output_end - output_start) / (input_end - input_start)) * (input - input_start)
<=>
output = To Min + (To Max - To Min) / (From Max - From Min) * (input - From Min)
```

We then just need to do the operations linearly.

Let's create a node group in order to reuse it wherever we want.

[image]

First operation, calculate `input - From Min`

[image]

Then, `From Max - From Min`

[image]

`To Max - To Min`

[image]

`(To Max - To Min) / (From Max - From Min)`

[image]

`(To Max - To Min) / (From Max - From Min) * (input - From Min)`

[image]

Finally, `(To Max - To Min) / (From Max - From Min) * (input - From Min) + To Min` :

[image]

for the sake of tidiness, remove the unneeded attributes, and output the geometry.

[image]

Here's a simple setup to generate a bunch of attributes to test out our node group.

[image]

Plug everything up, and use a control regular Map Range node to test it.

[image]

Use the new [Spreadsheet Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/spreadsheet.html) to analyse the data.

[image]

It's the same, yay !

Caveats, possible improvements :

- This group only accepts attributes. You could theoretically tweak it to accept floats with a Switch node (Blender 3.00 +), but the sheer number of possible configurations would make the node group very big and convoluted.
- This is a linear interpolation, meaning you would need to change the algorithm to add a damping coefficient if you want a smoother interpolation.
- Add an [Attribute Clamp](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_clamp.html) node at the end if you want the possibility to clamp output

Grab the file to test out the node group :

[image]

and here the attribute clamp node:

[image]

Comment: looks very promising...i check this out...!!

Comment: Of course. Perfect.

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you Gorgious! Works perfect...!! Just a little comment ;) The attribute clamp as it is wouldn't help, because it doesn't allow attributes in min and max, right? so i would have to "rebuild" this on my own like you did with the map range node. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @Gorgious: i added the nodetree for the attribute clamp node in your great answer. Hope that was ok for you.

Comment: @Chris Sure thing, thanks :)

Comment: by the way: your answer freed me from felt 40 superfluous nodes....! ;)