# Mapping a range of numbers to another range using math nodes / geometry nodes

Tags: mathematics, geometry-nodes

How can I have numbers **0-360** be mapped to a range from **-45 to 0 to +45** using math nodes / geometry nodes?  I was thinking of using the map range node with a mod node but got confused.

[image: img]

I also looked at [How to put an attribute value in "from Min" from "Attribute map range" node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227702/how-to-put-an-attribute-value-in-from-min-from-attribute-map-range-node/227706?r=SearchResults#227706)

Example:
**0-360** goes from **-45 < \theta < 45**

Comment: From Min: 0, From Max: 360, To Min: -45, To Max: 45. I don't know why you put the 0 step inbetween the -45 and 45...

Comment: I watched several map range videos and just got really confused..that `0` is supposed to be `\theta`.

Comment: Well, I see. Okay, but that's not necessary ;) You plug a value to be converted into the _Value_ input. In the _From_ section you give the range of input values you want to be mapped. In the _To_ section you put the range it should be mapped to. If you switch _Min_ and _Max_ in one section you can also map an ascending range to a descending range etc. If you activate _Clamp_ it means, values lower than _From Min_ will all be mapped to _To Min_ and everything higher than _From Max_ will get _To Max_. Without _Clamp_ those values will be interpolated relative to the mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Just to be able to mark this question as solved, here is a short answer from the comments:

*From Min* and *From Max* here define the range of values passed.

*To Min* and *To Max* define the range to which these values should be mapped.

The option *Clamp* limits the output to the values defined with *To Min* and *To Max*.

[image]

Tip: Possibly, since we are obviously dealing with angles here, you would need to use the Math node `To Radians` for further processing.